# How do I make my table look more aesthetic?

Tags: tables

I need help making my table look better. As of now, this is what I have:

[image]

However, I want it to look something like this:

[image]

Below is my code:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\tiny
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
 \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Process}} & \textbf{Welding Parameters} & \textbf{Adherend size} & 
\textbf{Welding speed} & \textbf{Consolidation} & \textbf{Configuration} & \textbf{Remarks} 
\\
\cline{2-7}
& Force, Amplitude, speed/time &  & Speed, (Number of welds) & Force,Time/speed &  &  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\caption{}
\end{table}enter code here
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The first step toward enlightenment, as far as LaTeX tables are concerned: Never, ever use the `\resizebox` sledgehammer.

Comment: Do please tell us which document class you employ, which paper size you use (A4? US letter?), and how wide the margins are -- or, equivalently, how wide the text block is supposed to be.

Comment: never use `\resizebox` on tables, you have no chance of having consistent fonts if you scale in this way.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the scant information the OP has provided, I'm assuming that the 5 data columns should be made as narrow as possible, in part to afford more space to the final column, labelled "Remarks". I will also assume that automatic line breaking should be enabled in the final column. Please advise if these assumptions are incorrect.

If these assumptions are correct, the following solution may be of interest. Note that I've used `\makecell` instructions in some of the header cells in order to make them as narrow as possible. Note further that I would not use **bold-facing** in the header cells, both because it's not needed and because it forces the header cells to become wider, needlessly deducting space from the all-important final column.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters as needed
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell,tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight \hangafter=1 \hangindent=1em}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\small % optional
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt} % default: 6pt
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l ccccc L @{}}
\toprule
Process & 
\makecell[t]{Welding\\parameters} & 
\makecell[t]{Adherend\\size} & 
\makecell[t]{Welding\\speed} &
\makecell[t]{Consoli-\\dation} & 
\makecell[t]{Configu-\\ration} & 
Remarks \\
\cmidrule{2-7}
& 
\makecell[t]{Force, ampl.,\\ speed/time} &  
& 
\makecell[t]{Speed\\(no.\ of welds)} & 
\makecell[t]{Force,\\time/speed} &  
\\
\midrule
aaa aaa aaa aaa & b & c & d & e & f & ggg hhh iii jjj kkk lll nnn mmm ooo ppp qqq \\
rrr rrr rrr rrr & s & t & u & v & w & xxx yyy zzz \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{A seven-column table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, but I also dislike the goal. A table with vertical rules is never a good (elegant, formal) table.

Beside that, the aim of use `\resizebox` is symptom of a bad design, as well as use the `\tiny` font, but without know the contents of the document, it is hard propose clever alternatives. Here is one, but taking several assumptions (e.g., that you need a portrait table with "normal" margins, that headers as "Force, Amplitude, speed/time" can be splitted into 3 columns and simplified, and that the contents will no need more widths that the headers). So, very probably it will not be suitable for your data, but I hope that anyway the example help in some way.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabulary,multirow}
\usepackage{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\footnotesize
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{@{}lCCCC>{\centering}p{6em}CCcp{3cm}@{}}\toprule
 \multirow{2}{*}{Process} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Welding Parameters} &  \multirow{2}{=}{\parbox{4em}{\centering Adherend  size}} & 
\multirow{2}{=}{\centering  Welding speed\par\tiny (No. welds)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Consolidation}  &  \\\cmidrule(rl){2-4}\cmidrule(rl){7-8}
 & Force & \mbox{Amplitude} & v/t &    &  & Force & t/v & Configuration  & Remarks \\\midrule
xxx  & xxxx & xxxx  &  xxx  & xxxx & xxxx &  xxx  & xxxx & xxxx & Whatever very important to take a lot of space. \\
xxx  & xxxx & xxxx  &  xxx  & xxxx & xxxx &  xxx  & xxxx & xxxx & Something also very mportant  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}%
\end{table}
\end{document}
```